# How to append a column value to a group header

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a list grouped by Name and I'd like to append their job title to the header. The Job Title column exists in the list and it is a lookup field.

So it would look like this:

John Smith - General Manager
[row]
[row]

Jane Brown - Executive Chef
[row]
[row]

Comment: What is the data/column type of Name field? Also, job title is main lookup value or additional/extended lookup column?

Comment: If Name & Job Title are different columns in the list and you are applying grouping on Name column, I don't think you will be able to add another column value (job title) in group heading.

Comment: The Name column is text Job Title is main lookup.

Comment: This example appends additional people properties to the group header but I assume its not pulling anything from the view itself but from stored 'People' info.
https://michelcarlo.com/2021/12/11/list-view-group-header-formatting-custom-icons-and-background-colours-by-status-value/

Comment: There are so many basic things you can't do in MS Lists. It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Lookup field as you mentioned. Unfortunately you are not able to use calculated fields too.

Solution can be:

1. **Create another text** field *"Name and Job"*
2. **Create Flow** starting o new/edited list item and **fill** *"Name and Job"* text field **with text values from Name and Lookup Job** fields as you wish to display them.
3. New *"Name and Job"* field **select in view for grouping**.

*Hope it helps!*

*Mark answer as accepted solution, if it works.*